# Значения определенной строки DBF или XLS приравнять к переменным в PHP коде

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть DBF'ка, которая при необходимости может стать XLS'кой. Требуется определенную строчку приравнять к переменным в PHP коде.

В инете нашел много аналогичных, но не подходящих, тем, наподобие отображения всего файла DBF/XLS, и при чем по всем столбикам. Мне же нужно выборочно.

К примеру, из файла base.dbf (или base.xls) из 5й строчки, значения в столбиках B,C,D,E, приравнять к переменным $b,$c,$d,$e. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как такое сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать можно всё, только зачем ?!

Работайте с этим файлом как с базой данных

**UPD:**

```
$db = dbase_open('/path/to/file.dbf', 1);
var_dump(dbase_get_record($db, 5));
dbase_close($db)
```

Да, нужна dbase библиотека для php

Comment: Ну... вот, прочитав много страниц в интернете, у меня серьезные сомнения, по поводу, что сделать можно все. ))) И я спрашиваю, не по тому, что кого-то хочу помучить. Просто нужно знать, как так сделать, что бы решить определенную задачу.

Comment: А может вы задачу сами надумали ? И нет никакой задачи если её решать по другому ?

Comment: Вот теоретически, если бы я попросил сказать, как добавить/удалить строчки в XSL файле, мне бы сказали "Погугли!" , или дали ссылки на ресурсы, которые я уже сам нашел.

Проблема в том, что нужно сделать именно то, что я написал выше, и к сожалению, в место решения, приходиться спорить, что мол этот вариант, единственный, для того, что мне нужно.

Скажу так - все, что можно было сделать "по другому", я уже нашел, и уже умею. на свой вопрос, вполне корректный, пока ответа найти не могу.

Comment: обновил

Comment: спасибо. буду довольствоваться этим. но в обще, ждал решения без доп. библиотек.