# Чтение данных из XLS в  PHP

Tags: php, excel

Как прочитать данные из ячейки в XLS документе с выводом через переменную PHP?

Поискав в интернете, пришел к выводу, что без `php_dbase.dll` никак. Дальше непробиваемая стена. Не знаю, как эту библиотеку применить. Хочется из файла excel.xls, лежащего прямо в директории сайта из первой страницы, из первой строки, из первого столбца (ячейка A1) прочитать значение, т.е. не показывать на странице, а просто приравнять к переменной.

Как можно ли "грохнуть" определенную строку/столбец?

Подскажите с командами.

Comment: А что вам мешает вместо XLS использовать CSV и уже парсить его как обычный текстовый файл?

Comment: а что МНЕ мешает в место XLS использовать BMP? ...извините, сорвалось, тупость сказал... почему для решения вопроса нужно менять вопрос? ну допустим в силу обновляемости XLS, и т.к. охота научиться использовать именно XLS... а еще в обще не знаю значение фразы "использовать CSV и уже парсить его" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая штуковина, как [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home).

А здесь написано, как с помощью PHPExcel можно [читать Excel-файлы с помощью PHPExcel](http://www.web-junior.net/chtenie-excel-fajjlov-s-pomoshhyu-phpexcel/).

Comment: уп-с ... немного не успел :)

Comment: по ссылке на web-junior самый адекватный вариант, но, кроме того,  просто вывод МНЕ НЕ НУЖЕН. ну, XLS файл, 20'000 строк с записями, и вуаля, вывод всех 20'000 в место первой (или другой нужной) строки, да и смысла просто показать - нет. я ж спросил как приравнять к переменной.

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание на [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) и [PHP-ExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/).

Answer (score 0):

У меня была немного похожая тема, не знаю, поможет нет...

[Значения определенной строки DBF или XLS приравнять к переменным в PHP коде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22844/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-dbf-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-xls-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5).

Comment: уже хоть что то, ну и как, с помощью этого, приравнять значение ячейки A1 в моем excel.xls скажем к $a1 ?